freeze when calling any shell command
To recreate the problem:

Create an .bashrc_emacs file :

# -*- shell-script -*-
export PATH="$PATH":~/SYNCHRO/bin/ # put the path to where net.ip.private is
export BOOTTIME=$(sys.boottime)


Create and chmod +x the sys.boottime script:

   #!/bin/bash
   last reboot | awk 'NR == 1 {print $5,$6,$7,$8}'


Evaluate this line of elisp code:

   (setenv "BASH_ENV" (expand-file-name "~/.bashrc_emacs"))

This should load the bashrc_emacs file prior to executing any shell command with  M-! 

Then call any shell command, like a simple echo "hello world!"

In my case, it simply freezes.
if I replace this line in the bashrc_emacs file:
export BOOTTIME=$(sys.boottime)

with this line:
export UP=$(last reboot | awk 'NR == 1 {print $5,$6,$7,$8}')

then everything works right.
it only freezes when I use that script,
which is in the path by the way.
you can even comment that line:
# export UP=$(last reboot | awk 'NR == 1 {print $5,$6,$7,$8}')
# or
# export BOOTTIME=$(sys.boottime)

and  M-! echo $BOOTTIME 
which should return last time your machine booted.
Any help appreciated.
This is Emacs 24 running on linux.


The file sys.boottime is a Bash script.
Bash will execute the file $BASH_ENV each time before it runs a script.
Command substitution $(sys.boottime) is put in the file $BASH_ENV.

There's an infinite recursion here, can you see that?

... and read the bash man page (search for BASH_ENV - it's a big page) for some usage guidelines. @shynur's point can be summarized: don't ever execute a script inside the BASH_ENV script. You should only use it to set environment variables to constant values and that only if necessary - I have never ever used BASH_ENV and I've written a lot of bash code (even when I should have known better...)

Or, in this case, unset the BASH_ENV variable and then reset it.
